# How to Inject a SharedPreferences Class as DataManager into app?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, sharedpreferences

I'm getting this error while i'm trying to Build/Rebuild :

```
error: ir.atlaspio.roshdbookstore.DI.Components.ApplicationComponent scoped with @ir.atlaspio.roshdbookstore.DI.Scopes.ApplicationScope may not reference bindings with different scopes:
@Singleton class ir.atlaspio.roshdbookstore.Data.Prefs.AtlasPreferencesHelper
```

I'm trying to improve my code base on some projects and tutorials, right now i'm trying to doing dependency injection for SharedPreferences, which i've got above problem. It's not long time since i'm messing with Dagger 2 And DI, so excuse my beginner question and help me about this to find out where i'm doing this wrong. also there are some codes which they will inject `SharedPrefereces` but what i want is to use My own DataManager to do it right.
So here's how i created my project(Which is base on some tutorials):

Explaining Section(Which could be obvious for you guys): adding some method to set data into sharedpref.
AtlasPreferencesHelper :

```
@Singleton
public class AtlasPreferencesHelper implements PreferencesHelper {


private static final String PREF_KEY_USER_LOGGED_IN_MODE = "PREF_KEY_USER_LOGGED_IN_MODE";
private static final String PREF_KEY_FIRST_TIME_RUN_MODE = "PREF_KEY_FIRST_TIME_RUN_MODE";

private final SharedPreferences atlasPrefs;

@Inject
public AtlasPreferencesHelper(@ApplicationContext Context context,
                              @PreferenceInfo String prefFileName) {
    atlasPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(prefFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
public int getCurrentUserLoggedInMode() {
    return atlasPrefs.getInt(PREF_KEY_USER_LOGGED_IN_MODE,
            DataManager.LoggedInMode.LOGGED_IN_MODE_LOGGED_OUT.getType());
}

@Override
public void setCurrentUserLoggedInMode(DataManager.LoggedInMode mode) {
    atlasPrefs.edit().putInt(PREF_KEY_USER_LOGGED_IN_MODE, mode.getType()).apply();
}

@Override
public int getCurrentFirstTimeStat() {
    return atlasPrefs.getInt(PREF_KEY_FIRST_TIME_RUN_MODE,
            DataManager.FirstTimeRun.FIRST_TIME_RUN_TRUE.getFrType());
}

@Override
public void setCurrentFirstTimeStat(DataManager.FirstTimeRun fMode) {
    atlasPrefs.edit().putInt(PREF_KEY_FIRST_TIME_RUN_MODE, fMode.getFrType()).apply();
}
}
```

Explains : interface to be implemented in AtlasPreferencesHelper.
PreferenceHelper :

```
public interface PreferencesHelper {

int getCurrentUserLoggedInMode();

void setCurrentUserLoggedInMode(DataManager.LoggedInMode mode);

int getCurrentFirstTimeStat();

void setCurrentFirstTimeStat(DataManager.FirstTimeRun fMode);
}
```

Explains: Doing Job and getting access to activity to use methods.
AppDataManager :

```
public class AppDataManager implements DataManager {

private static final String TAG = "AppDataManager";

private final Context mContext;
private final PreferencesHelper mPrefencesHelper;

@Inject
public AppDataManager(@ApplicationContext Context context, PreferencesHelper prefencesHelper) {
    mContext = context;
    mPrefencesHelper = prefencesHelper;
}

@Override
public void setUserAssLoggedOut() {
    setCurrentUserLoggedInMode(LoggedInMode.LOGGED_IN_MODE_LOGGED_OUT);
}

@Override
public int getCurrentUserLoggedInMode() {
    return mPrefencesHelper.getCurrentUserLoggedInMode();
}

@Override
public void setCurrentUserLoggedInMode(LoggedInMode mode) {
    mPrefencesHelper.setCurrentUserLoggedInMode(mode);
}

@Override
public int getCurrentFirstTimeStat() {
    return mPrefencesHelper.getCurrentFirstTimeStat();
}

@Override
public void setCurrentFirstTimeStat(FirstTimeRun fMode) {
    mPrefencesHelper.setCurrentFirstTimeStat(fMode);
}
}
```

Explains : DataManager interface implemented to AppDataManager
DataManager :

```
public interface DataManager extends PreferencesHelper {

void setUserAssLoggedOut();


enum LoggedInMode {

    LOGGED_IN_MODE_LOGGED_OUT(0),
    LOGGED_IN_MODE_SERVER(1);

    private final int mType;

    LoggedInMode(int type)
    {
        mType = type;
    }

    public int getType()
    {
        return mType;
    }
}

enum FirstTimeRun {

    FIRST_TIME_RUN_FALSE(0),
    FIRST_TIME_RUN_TRUE(1);

    private final int frType;

    FirstTimeRun(int rType){
        frType = rType;
    }

    public int getFrType()
    {
        return frType;
    }
}

}
```

Explains : Components which, Context provide context, Retrofit Provide retrofit and SharedPref will provide Datamanager and SharedPref
ApplicationComponent :

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {ContextModule.class,
    RetrofitModule.class,
    SharedPrefModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

MyAtlasAPI getApiReference();

DataManager getDataManager();

@ApplicationContext
Context getContext();

void injectApplication(AtlasApplication atlasApplication);
}
```

Explains : Module that will be implement in component for datamanager and sharedpref
SharedPrefModule :

```
@Module
public class SharedPrefModule {


@Provides
@PreferenceInfo
String providePreferenceName() {
    return AppConstants.PREF_NAME;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
DataManager provideDataManager(AppDataManager appDataManager)
{
    return appDataManager;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
PreferencesHelper providePreferencesHelper(AtlasPreferencesHelper atlasPreferencesHelper)
{
    return atlasPreferencesHelper;
}
}
```

Comment: You are using `@ApplicationScope` on the component, but you are using `@Singleton` on the actual class. Use either one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is telling it all. You're trying to reference to a module with a different scope than your component.

Looking at you `ApplicationComponent`:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {ContextModule.class,
RetrofitModule.class,
SharedPrefModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent { }
```

It's using the `ApplicationScope`

Your ApplicationComponent is then referring to `SharedPrefModule`.
If we take a look at that class:

```
@Module
public class SharedPrefModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    PreferencesHelper providePreferencesHelper(AtlasPreferencesHelper atlasPreferencesHelper) { 
        return atlasPreferencesHelper;
    }
}
```

This module is using the `Singleton` scope.
Finally your `AtlasPreferencesHelper` is also scoped with `Singleton`:

```
@Singleton
public class AtlasPreferencesHelper {}
```

What you wanna do is align these scopes.
So either annotate the `ApplicationComponent` with `@Singleton` or use the `@Application` for all the modules within your `ApplicationComponent`

Comment: hey man. i've already founded. and the problem was just what u said. but I'll flag this as correct answer since it's correct. Thanks